# True or False elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

True or False: If E1 and E2 are two n x n elementary matrices then E1 x E2 is an elementary matrix.

Comment: "An elementary matrix is a matrix which differs from the identity matrix by **one single** elementary row operation." ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix)) So, what do you think this implies?

Comment: False because any invertible matrix can be written as the product of elementary matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False.

An elementary matrix is a matrix that differs from the identity matrix by one elementary row operation. That allows you to swap two rows (or columns), add a multiple of one row (or column) to another, or multiply one row (or column) by some non-zero constant. Multiplying two elementary matrices together loosely corresponds to performing two elementary operations and so their product is, in general, not an elementary matrix. As a very simple example of two elementary matrices that multiply to a non-elementary matrix,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}.
$$